# Shortest path optimization as walls are removed from the 2D grid

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, shortest-path

I have a 2D grid with some starting locations and some target locations. Each cell is either empty (0) or has a wall (1). I need to find the shortest path from any starting location to the closest target location. The only movement is in the 4 cardinal directions and vertical movement will be preferred in the case of a tie (there are multiple cardinal directions from the current cell that result in the same shortest path).

This is a fairly simple problem that just requires a multi-source BFS from all target locations to precompute how far away each cell is from the closest target location. Then given a starting location, I can simply look at all 4 neighbors and pick the one with the smallest value and iterate until I reach the target.

However, there is a twist. As my thing is moving through the grid to reach a target location (say one cell each second), certain walls may be removed from the grid. You know the locations of the walls that are removed in the grid, but you do not know this information beforehand. Whenever a wall is removed, there is a chance that your shortest path changes at that instant. As a result, I am currently having to recompute the entire multi-source BFS each time a wall is removed and then continue pathfinding, which is slow.

For example, say I start at `(0, 0)` and want to reach `(2, 0)` and the shortest path is `(0,0) -> (0,1) -> (0,2) -> (1,2) -> (2,2) -> (2,1) -> (2,0)`. As I am traversing my path and reach `(0, 1)`, the wall at `(1, 0)` is broken, creating a new shorter path `(0,0) -> (0,1) -> (0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (2, 0)`.

Is there a way to perform updates/figure out the path without having to recompute most (if not all) of the graph? The only optimization that I can think of is to run the multi-source BFS until it visits the thing's current location, but I would prefer something faster if possible.

Comment: Are you removing a single piece or several walls at once? For a single piece, you can calculate the value of this cell, using the lowest adiacent value, then "flood" this value propagating it only to cells with higher value.

Comment: @Rocco In most cases, it will be a single piece every few seconds. However, there is no constraint, and multiple pieces could be removed at once. How does the solution change if we need to consider multiple walls removed at once?

Comment: @PranayAgrawal: Rocco's approach will still work provided that you process the now-wall-free cells in increasing order of their lowest adjacent value (note -- this could change after each "flooding"!). This is because the cell with lowest adjacent value cannot have its lowest adjacent value improved by flooding any of the other cells first.

Comment: In addition to @PranayAgrawal (BTW, thank you) comment, when multiple walls are deleted at once you should calculate all temporary values for the relative cells from the adjacent ones, then keep these cells and values in an separate list. Start expanding the BFS from the lowest value cell, if one of the other now-wall-free cells is reached with a lower value then just delete it from the list, if the cell is not reached yet but its value is equal to the current BFS expansion then remove it from the list and add to the BFS queue. Note that in worst case you have to expand BFS on the whole grid.

Comment: I think I understand the solution now. Is this a known problem already with code online? If not I will attempt to implement it in the near future. Also if only a single piece is removed, is it valid to use the lowest adjacent value and then only "flood" this value to higher values until there are 1) no more higher values or 2) I reach the cell my thing is currently on?

Comment: For multi-walls, sort the cell-value pair in a separate list called `walls`. Create temp variable `i=1`. Add the first wall to my BFS queue and flood to higher values. The first time I try to insert a value of `walls[i].value` into the BFS queue, I'll also add the (walls[idx].coords, walls[i].value) into the BFS queue and `++i`. If I already visited this cell, then the algorithm would implicitly not propagate this value since the neighbors would have less value. If I finish my BFS before, I process the next `i`. Does this sound right? Note that the grid may be disjoint before any wall breaks.